# How to show a specific month in android CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I want to show a specific month to user using android CalendarView. Please help me to implement this functionality. I wrote following code but it is not working.

```
  CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(2016, 6, 1);

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.set(2016, 6, 30);

    calendarView.setMinDate(calendar1.DATE);
    calendarView.setMaxDate(calendar2.DATE);
```

Following output is coming when i am trying to run the app using above code.

[image]

Comment: which month you want to show

Comment: Hint: What is the the value of [`Calendar.DATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE)?

Comment: June, month i want to show.

Comment: Nope, it is the constant value of 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is the the value of [`Calendar.DATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE)? Documentation says 5, and so when you call this method, you are saying "5 milliseconds past Jan 01, 1970."

> [**setMinDate(long minDate)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setMinDate(long))
>
> Sets the minimal date supported by this CalendarView in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

Basically, that is a static field, and probably not the value that you want.

Perhaps you want [`getTimeInMillis()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) which returns the `long` for the value that you set the date at?

```
calendarView.setMinDate(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
calendarView.setMaxDate(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Thank You. I have just changed (calendar1.DATE) to (calendar1.getTimeInMillis()). And now i got what i wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: I need one more help. If you have time then please try to help me.

Comment: I need to show dated in CalendarView with different background colours. How can we implement this type of functionality like we need to show 2 Aug 2016, 15 Aug 2016 and 18 Aug 2016 dates into red color and remaining dates of this month in green color. So how can we implement this type of functionality using android CalendarView?

Comment: Comments are for clarification on existing answers. You are welcome to [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Alright, well, I don't know have a quick answer to that anyways. CalendarView is useful for showing a calendar, and that's about it. You'd have to implement some extension of it to do any fancy customization.

Comment: Okay. I'll try with some extension to get my desired functionality. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As From my experience i always used Calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, year) method to set year and Calender.set(Calendar.MONTH, month) method to set month and Calender.set(Calendar.DAY,day) method to set day . So i am suggesting you to do same ,

```
    String date = "1/6/2016";
    String parts[] = date.split("/");
    int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

And now set the selected date in the calendar view by doing

```
  mCalendarView.setDate (milliTime, true, true);
```

Comment: Okay. Thank You. I have implement the same code as you have written here. Thank You very much brother.

Comment: I need one more help help from you. Please help me brother.

Comment: I need to show dated in CalendarView with different background colours. How can we implement this type of functionality like we need to show 2 Aug 2016, 15 Aug 2016 and 18 Aug 2016 dates into red color and remaining dates of this month in green color. So how can we implement this type of functionality using android CalendarView?

Comment: Okay. Thanks Brother.