# How to show only a specific month on Android CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I want to show a specific month on CardView **without** NEXT and PREVIOUS arrow to navigate the calendar. If I want to show February 2010 user must see only February 2010. They can't go next or previous month.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062935/6200296) Stack Overflow answer to show a specific month but it's not working for me. It shows all time the current date and month for my case. I'm not sure is it possible or not to disable NEXT-PREVIOUS navigation.

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="megaminds.dailyeditorialword.Fragments.CalendarViewFragment">

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarViewT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="7">

</CalendarView>
```

`onCreateView` of my fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_view, container, false);

    int year = 2010, month = 2, day = 1;

    CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarViewT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day); //want to show full month of February 2010

    calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    return view;
}
```

How can I show only February month without next-previous navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Calendar febFirst=Calendar.getInstance();

febFirst.set(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

calendar.setMinDate(febFirst.getTimeInMillis());

Calendar febLast=Calendar.getInstance();

febLast.set(2017, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);

calendar.setMaxDate(febLast.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.setDate(febFirst.getTimeInMillis());
```

where `calendar` is the `CalendarView`.

[image: CalendarView, locked to February 2017, on Nexus 5 running Android 6]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine. Another issue, 

here always mark the 1st date of that month. Can I disable it? If I show the current month the date selector will select the current date. If I show another month (not the current month) then selector should not select the first date by default. Is it possible?

Comment: @HasanAbdullah: "here always mark the 1st date of that month" -- no, it marks the date that you request via `setDate()`. "Can I disable it?" -- not that I am aware of, since the point of `CalendarView` is to let the user pick a date. Perhaps the right answer is for you to not be using `CalendarView`, but instead use [some library that is more in lines with your desired feature set](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27).

Answer (score 1):

```
int day = 16;
int month =8;
int year =2017;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
     long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
mCalendarView.setDate (milliTime, true, true);
```

Here mCalendarView is the Android calendar view

Comment: It's showing the specific month with NEXT and PREVIOUS button.

Comment: @HasanAbdullah you can use Android custom calendarview for more styling, you can play with next and previous buttons on it