# How to show only 2019 calendar on Android CalendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

Is there a way to show only 2019 calendar in `calendarView`?

I mean no PREVIOUS arrow before jan 2019 and no next arrow after dec 2019

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show only a specific month on Android CalendarView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810262/how-to-show-only-a-specific-month-on-android-calendarview)

Comment: you can achive this by seeting min and max date of calender view

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2019, 0, 1);
calendarView.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
c.set(2019, 11, 31);
calendarView.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

`CalendarView`

Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView

**android:maxDate**

The maximal date shown by this calendar view in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

May be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character;

Related methods:

[setMaxDate(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView#attr_android:maxDate)

**android:minDate**

The minimal date shown by this calendar view in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

May be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character;

Related methods:

[setMinDate(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView#attr_android:minDate)

Answer (score 0):

First you must set min date like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2019, 0, 1);
calendarView.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

And set the max date like below:

```
calendar.set(2019, 12, 31);
calendarView.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```